# Django: Transactions and how to avoid wrong counting?

Tags: python, django, transactions

I am currently struggling with a topic connected to transactions. I implemented a discount functionality. Whenever a sale is made with a discount code, the counter `redeemed_quantity` is increased by + 1.

Now I thought about the case. What if one or more users redeem a discount at the same time? Assuming `redeemed_quantity` is 10. User 1 buys the product and `redeemed_quantity` increases by +1 = 11. Now User 2 clicked on 'Pay' at the same time and again `redeemed_quantity` increases by +1 = 11. Even so, it should be 12. I learned about `@transaction.atomic` but I think the way I implemented them here will not help me with what I am actually trying to prevent. Can anyone help me with that?

view.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'website/index.html'
    initial_price_of_course = 100000  # TODO: Move to settings

    def check_discount_and_get_price(self):
        discount_code_get = self.request.GET.get('discount')
        discount_code = Discount.objects.filter(code=discount_code_get).first()
        if discount_code:
            discount_available = discount_code.available()
            if not discount_available:
                messages.add_message(
                    self.request,
                    messages.WARNING,
                    'Discount not available anymore.'
                )
        if discount_code and discount_available:
            return discount_code, self.initial_price_of_course - discount_code.value
        else:
            return discount_code, self.initial_price_of_course

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['stripe_pub_key'] = settings.STRIPE_PUB_KEY
        discount_object, course_price = self.check_discount_and_get_price()
        context['course_price'] = course_price
        return context

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        email = request.POST.get('stripeEmail')
        discount_object, course_price = self.check_discount_and_get_price()
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=course_price,
            currency='EUR',
            description='My Description',
            source=token,
            receipt_email=email,
        )

        if charge.paid:
            if discount_object:
                discount_object.redeemed_quantity += 1
                discount_object.save()
            order = Order(
                total_gross=course_price,
                discount=discount_object
            )
            order.save()

        return redirect('website:index')
```

models.py

```
class Discount(TimeStampedModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    value = models.IntegerField()  # Smallest currency unit, as amount charged
    max_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    redeemed_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def available(self):
            available_quantity = self.max_quantity - self.redeemed_quantity
            if available_quantity > 0:
                return True


class Order(TimeStampedModel):
    total_gross = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.ForeignKey(
        Discount,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,  # Can't delete discount if used.
        related_name='orders',
        null=True,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the handling of the incrementation to the database in order to avoid the race condition in your code by using [django's F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F

# ...
discount_object.redeemed_quantity = F('redeemed_quantity') + 1 
discount_object.save()
```

From the docs with a completely analogous example:

> Although `reporter.stories_filed = F('stories_filed') + 1` looks like a normal Python assignment of value to an instance attribute, in fact it’s an SQL construct describing an operation on the database.
>
> When Django encounters an instance of `F()`, it overrides the standard Python operators to create an encapsulated SQL expression; in this case, one which instructs the database to increment the database field represented by reporter.stories_filed.

Comment: Oh wow, that's just perfect. Never heard of this, but exactly what I was looking for. Than you very much! Do I even need `@transaction.atomic` in that case? I read a lot about it, but still not sure if I should keep it.

Comment: You don't need it for this case. I feel it is generally a decent Idea to activate the `atomic_requests` setting for your database backend, so that all db changes during a request causing a server error are rolled back. As the other answer points out, atomicity of a code block does not avoid race conditions, but ensures that a series of db queries is never just partially executed.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a piece of a synchronous code. It means that every request you make to the server is processed individually. This problem could arise, when there are multiple server-workers (for example uwsgi workers), but again - it's practically impossible to do this. We run a webshop application with multiple workers and something like this never happend.

But back to the question - if you want to query the database to increase a value by one, see schwobaseggl's answer.

The last thing is that I think you misunderstand what transaction.atomic() does. Simply put it rolls back any queries made to the database in a function if function exits with an error to the state when function was called. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730574/5800369) and [this piece of documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly). Maybe it will clear some things up.