# Django Unable to rollback with try-exception block for atomic transactions

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, atomic

One of my view in Django executes save operations on 6-7 tables. I want these transactions to be atomic I,e if the 5th or 6th transaction fail I want to rollback all the previous saves.
The view contains a try-except block to handle the exceptions raised.

It looks something like this:

```
@transaction.atomic
def my_view(request):
    sid = transaction.savepoint()
    try:
        Table1.save()
        Table2.save()
        Table3.save()
        Table4.save()
        Table5.save()
        Table6.save()
        Table7.save()  # This might fail. In case of failure I want to rollback saves from Table1 to Table6

        transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
        return JsonResponse({"Status": 0, "Data": str(e)})
```

I've tried the above and Table7.save() has failed and Table1 to Table6 rollback has not happened.
I want to return the JSON response as `{"Status": 0, Data: "Error That occurred"}` in all the cases.
I don't want to re-raise the exception in except block as done in [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730385/django-rollback-save-with-transaction-atomic)

What should I do to return a proper JSONResponse and rollback everything in case of failure?

Comment: `Table2.save()` doesn't look right, is this the exact code or just something to summarize the question?

Comment: A summarize version. You can import any model(Table as class) from models.py and save a record for that model(Table).

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730574/1685980):

> **transaction.atomic** will execute a transaction on the database if your
>   view produces a response without errors. Because you're catching the
>   exception yourself, it appears to Django that your view executed just
>   fine. If you catch the exception, you need to handle it yourself

An alternative approach is to use `transaction.atomic` inside `with` (as context manager), which will ensure a commit or rollback (again suggested on the same link and also explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly))

```
def my_view(request):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            Table1.save()
            Table2.save()
            Table3.save()
            Table4.save()
            Table5.save()
            Table6.save()
            Table7.save()  # This might fail. In case of failure I want to rollback saves from Table1 to Table6

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        return JsonResponse({"Status": 0, "Data": str(e)})
```

Comment: We handle it ourself by using transaction.savepoint() right. Still, I'm unable to do any rollbacks. using a transaction.atomic inside "with" and catching the exception as above is not helping. So how to handle it ourselves with try-except clause was my question.

Comment: @shreesh katti, the answer works fine. debug your code and make sure you're getting a failure. for example, run an exception in `save()` method of `Table7` and test again